# Puppeteer with proxy per page not working any more?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

UseProxy(page) doesn't appear to be working any more on the latest version of Edge and Chrome. I have spent days testing every example I can find. They all appear to be 3-4 years old and none of them work any more. I don't want to use args on the browser. I need to open multiple pages in one browser all with different proxies. I have tried a VPN just incase my IPS was blocking which hasn't made a difference. I have checked the logs on my proxy server, the code isn't even attempting to contact my proxy server. Here is my code...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const useProxy = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');

(async () => {

    const username = 'usernamehere';
    const password = 'passwordhere';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe',
        headless: false,
        args: [`--mute-audio`, '--disable-web-security'],
    });

    page = await browser.newPage();

    await useProxy(page, 'http://proxyiphere:proxyporthere');
    await page.authenticate({ username, password });
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');
    page.goto("https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=whatsmyip");

    setTimeout(function () { browser.close(); }, 5000000);

})();
```